# Best practice to reload page when popup closed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**The task at hand:**
After creating a form the user gets a page, where - depending on the form's answer - a few links appear. These links provide a popup window to create datasheet relevant to the question. Also in front of them there is a red cross to indicate it is not done.

**The question:**
How can I achieve that, if a datasheet is created (popup closed with the create button) the related question's red cross change to a green tick and remove the link?

**The environment:**
ASP.NET MVC

Since the question is downvoted here is the reason why posted this question: I haven't got the slightest clue about how to achieve it. IMHO instead of downvoting, an answer would be more helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();
            if (Session["PlanList"] == null)
            {
                plans = GetPlans();
                Session["PlanList"] = plans;
            }
            else
            {
                plans = Session["PlanList"] as List<Plan>;
            }

            return View(plans);
        }

        public ActionResult PopupSave()
        {
            return PartialView("_PopupSave");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PopupSave(int PlanId)
        {
            List<Plan> plans = Session["PlanList"] as List<Plan>;

            plans.Where(p => p.PlanId == PlanId).FirstOrDefault().Created = true;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public List<Plan> GetPlans()
        {
            List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                plans.Add(new Plan()
                {
                    PlanId = i,
                    PlanName = "Plan nr " + i,
                    Created = false
                });
            }

            return plans;
        }

    }
    public class Plan
    {
        public int PlanId { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        public bool Created { get; set; }
    }
```

The view itself is quite simple, like the popup control.